# powershell Syntax error ')' in script

Tags: powershell, syntax, syntax-error

im a writing a script in powershell that show services running on a computer and start the services that is not running.
My command is the following

## Show all services on Powershell with startmode "Auto"

```
$shse = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_service -Computername pshells '
    -Filter "startmode = 'auto'" |
    ConvertTo-Html
```

## Service start all services with status = stopped.

```
$Service = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_service - Computername pshells '
    -Filter "startmode = 'auto'")

If ($Service.status -eq "Stopped"){
        Start-Service}

Else {}
```

## Convert Output to HTML.

```
ConvertTo-Html -body "$shse " |

Out-File C:\Scripts\Service.htm
```

When running this in powershell i get this error

```
At line:6 char:30
+     -Filter "startmode = 'auto'")
+                                 ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordExceptio 
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: I can't seem to fix the problem? when removing ')' the whole parameter is not valid

Comment: As far as I can see there is something wrong with your quote pairs: the single quote behind `pshells` is not closed.

Comment: What did you edit Rohit? It is still not valid

Comment: The line continuation character is not a `'` but a `\``.

Comment: and you have a space between `-` and `Computername`

Comment: That does not change anything, changing the above "errors"

Comment: Post a screenshot of your **actual** code or close the question.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName pshells  | where {$_.StartType -EQ 'Automatic' -and $_.Status -eq 'Stopped'} | Start-Service
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your existing code with this:

```
$Services =Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_service -Computername pshells -Filter "startmode = 'auto'"
foreach($service in $Services)
{
    If ($Service.state -eq "Stopped"){Start-Service}
    Else {"Service is already running."}
}
```

Few things you need to keep in mind , if you wish to use a line continuation then you should use *baktick(`) not single-quote(')* .

You are getting all the services status and you wish to start them all if stopped. So as a whole it will all the return you as **OK** since you were checking status. You should *check state not status*.

As a whole if it is returning and in case any of them is already running, then PS will have conflict in the condition, thats when you should use *foreach* loop.

Iterate each value you got in $services, check the state and take necessary action and loop over ; proceed with the same for the next one unless the list is exhausted.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

So i got the command to work, i typed in the following

```
Do
{

$shse = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_service -Computername WIN-9HMIGR3QFE6 -Filter "startmode = 'auto'" |
    ConvertTo-Html

$Service = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_service -Computername WIN-9HMIGR3QFE6 -Filter "startmode = 'auto'")

If ($Service.status -eq "Stopped"){

        Start-Service}

Else {}

ConvertTo-Html -body "$shse " |

Out-File C:\Test\Service01.html

Start-sleep -Seconds 600

}until ($infinity)
```

It created an html, where i can look at the services... But there is one problem, when i close down a service, the script is set to start all scripts again after 600 seconds, but service never gets up again.. So now the stopped-start service function is not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

On the line:

```
$Service = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_service - Computername pshells '
    -Filter "startmode = 'auto'")
```

You aren't using a back-tick (`) you're using a single quote (').  It should be a back-tick to escape the new line.